# Does any multiplicative combination of vector and matrix result in an eigen vector and value?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a vector v and a transformation matrix A, both comprised of real numbers. Multiplying v and A together, do we necessarily get an eigen vector and value?

Comment: What? You mean if $Av = av$ for some $a \in mathbb{R}$, so if any $v$ is an eigenvector for every matrix $A$? If this is your question then NO, not at all.

Comment: Not every vector in the domain is an eigenvector in general.

Comment: So normally, in $Av=av$, the left-hand and right-hand $v$ are the same vector? ( I just assumed the use of v on both sides in the standard notation was lazy notation--as in one glyph was being used to denote any vector selected from the set of all vectors, including possibly two distinct, non-isomorphic vectors )

Comment: Yes the $v$ in $Av=av$ is the same nonzero vector $v$ on both sides. However it cannot be any $v$ that satisfies this equation.

Comment: @Dave I see. So, given any real valued transformation matrix, there may be zero, one, or many eigen vectors for that matrix?

Comment: The eigenvalues are given by the characteristics polynomial of $A$, and for each eigenvalue there is a subspace of the domain which is called an eigenspace. So really there are infinitely many eigenvectors, but a finite number of eigenvalues for a finite size square matrix.

Comment: @Dave I see. Just to be sure, here the term eigen value is the scalar ( often denoted by lambda ) that multiples a given eigen vector?

Comment: Yes. The eigenvector it multiplies belongs to the eigenvalue's corresponding eigenspace.